# JsonSchema definition path and subschema re-use

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Lets say I have two schemas defined as follows -

```
ADDRESS_CLASS_SCHEMA_DEFINITION = {
  "title": "Address",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "country_code": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/CountryCode"
    },
    "city_code": {
      "title": "City Code",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "zipcode": {
      "title": "Zipcode",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address_str": {
      "title": "Address Str",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "country_code",
    "city_code",
    "zipcode"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "CountryCode": {
      "title": "CountryCode",
      "description": "An enumeration.",
      "enum": [
        "CA",
        "USA",
        "UK"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}


EMPLOYEE_CLASS_SCHEMA_DEFINITION = {
  "title": "Employee",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "title": "Id",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "title": "Email",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "telephone": {
      "title": "Telephone",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Address"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "email"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "Address": ADDRESS_CLASS_SCHEMA_DEFINITION
  }
}
```

I'm trying to re-use sub-schema definitions by defining a constant and referencing them individually in definitions (for example address-schema is referenced through constant in employee-schema definition). This approach works for individual schemas, however there seems to be a `json-pointer` path issue for `Employee` schema - `#/definitions/CountryCode` wouldn't resolve in Employee schema. I was assuming that `#/definitions/CountryCode` would be a relative path on `Address` schema as its scope is defined on a sub-schema, but my understanding seems wrong. I can make it work by flattening out like below, however I donot want to take this route -

```
{
  "title": "Employee",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "title": "Id",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "title": "Email",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "telephone": {
      "title": "Telephone",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Address"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "email"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "CountryCode": {
      "title": "CountryCode",
      "description": "An enumeration.",
      "enum": [
        "CA",
        "USA",
        "UK"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Address": {
      "title": "Address",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "country_code": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/CountryCode"
        },
        "city_code": {
          "title": "City Code",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "zipcode": {
          "title": "Zipcode",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address_str": {
          "title": "Address Str",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "country_code",
        "city_code",
        "zipcode"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how to fix this, I've briefly looked into jsonschema-bundling and using `$id` but from best practices it seems like the general recommendation is to use `$id` when dealing with URI's alone. Would like to know about best practices and how to fix this problem, would also appreciate if someone can point me on how to use `$id` correctly (for example, constant based approach seems to work when I provide identifiers like `$id: Address`, `$id: Employee`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you unroll your example, the `CountryCode` schema definition is nested into two levels of `definitions`: a) the defs of Employee b) the defs of Address. But referencing the `CountryCode` via "#/definitions/CountryCode" only checks in the first level. I've not seen nested definitions before and am not sure if it is supported. Normally I unroll them into the top layer. However, maybe `"#/definitions/Address/definitions/CountryCode" ` works?

Comment: Yes, that works but as I said, I want to define through constants and the constant schema should be able to exist by itself. I can make it work by flattening out definitions when there are nested schemas. But wondering if this can be cleanly handled through `$id`

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema implementations work in JSON land. When you combine your schemas in your example above, presumably in javascript/node.js, by the time it gets to the JSON Schema implementation for validation execution, any knowledge that there were separate schemas is lost. (It's generally not considered that this approach is the best approach.)

The EASY fix here SHOULD be just to define `$id` in each of the roots of your schemas. These should be a fully qualfied URI. It doesn't really matter what they are at this point. They could be `https://example.com/a` and `https://example.com/b`. Then, in the primary schema, you can do `$ref: https://example.com/b`.

Implementations should provide you with a way to load in your other/non-primary schemas so the `$id` values can be stored in an index. Using `$id` in your other schema with a fully qualified URI will signify a "resource boundary".

https://json-schema.hyperjump.io is the only web playground to support multiple files/schemas/"Schema Resources", so you can test this out there to confirm your expectations.

Not all implementations make it easy or even provide a means to import your other schemas, but they should.

If you have follow up questions, feel free to leave a comment, or join the JSON Schema slack server if it would be off-topic for StackOverflow.